# How to select QTreeWidgetItem by clicking its item-widget

Tags: python, pyqt

This code creates `QTreeWidget` with `QComboBox` and `QLineEdit` set as the `item widgets`.
If to follow these steps:

1. Right after this dialog opens...
2. Click the item (not its item-widget). Item's background color turns blue.
3. Now click any item-widget of another item (Combobox or LineEdit).

The item the combobox is assigned to as the item-widget gets selected (turns blue). Any other attempts to select the item by clicking its item-widget fail. You would have to close dialog and re-open it again. Since this happens only once.

Is it possible to make this feature persistent... so every time an item-widget is clicked the item holding it gets selected as well making a full impression the item and its item-widgets is the same thing. As it acts by 
default I have to click the item itself to make it selected.

### [image]

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Tree, self).__init__()
            for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
                item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
                item.setText(0, each)
                self.addTopLevelItem(item)
                self.setItemWidget(item, 1, QtGui.QComboBox())
                self.setItemWidget(item, 2, QtGui.QLineEdit())
            self.setColumnCount(5)
            self.resize(360,240)
            self.show()

    tree=Tree()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use have to use `mousePressEvent` (again) to implemented when item in widget has Press;

```
.
.
.
comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.setItemWidget(item, 1, comboBox)
self.setItemWidget(item, 2, lineEdit)
# Set new event
comboBox.mousePressEvent = partial(self.mousePressEventChild, currentQTreeWidgetItem = item, child = comboBox)
lineEdit.mousePressEvent = partial(self.mousePressEventChild, currentQTreeWidgetItem = item, child = lineEdit)
.
.
.

def mousePressEventChild (self, QMouseEvent, currentQTreeWidgetItem = None, child = None):
    if isinstance(currentQTreeWidgetItem, QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem): # <- Check this widget has QTreeWidgetItem.
        self.setCurrentItem(currentQTreeWidgetItem) # <- set current index by QTreeWidgetItem.
    super(child.__class__, child).mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent) # <- Default old mouse press event.
```

---

Full example code;

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
            lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            self.setItemWidget(item, 1, comboBox)
            self.setItemWidget(item, 2, lineEdit)
            comboBox.mousePressEvent = partial(self.mousePressEventChild, currentQTreeWidgetItem = item, child = comboBox)
            lineEdit.mousePressEvent = partial(self.mousePressEventChild, currentQTreeWidgetItem = item, child = lineEdit)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

    def mousePressEventChild (self, QMouseEvent, currentQTreeWidgetItem = None, child = None):
        if isinstance(currentQTreeWidgetItem, QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
            self.setCurrentItem(currentQTreeWidgetItem)
        super(child.__class__, child).mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Click event Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent

---

Regards,